# API not show when start running program

Tags: flutter, button, events, calendar

My program is calendar event it will show event name from the day I select, so when I start a program is will shown no event data for the day because I program it if the day not have event it will show but, when start a program for the day that have event it will show no event too, I need to manually click the day to make it show the event.
Here is the link of the clip that I met my problem:
https://youtu.be/f0MjPBnbsM0

I was trying to make it when I start the program it will show API correctly and when I click reset it will back to the current time my API is not appearing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.